# Mongo search: $or object seems to work like $and

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have two fields - firstname and lastname in my mongo collection that I'm trying to search from a single 'name' textbox with '$or'. The search looks like this:

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "firstname": {
        "$regex": ".*Za"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "$regex": ".*Za"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I use just the firstname or lastname value alone (i.e. comment out either the firstname or lastname object), then the search works as expected.

But together, this is only matching names where both firstname AND the lastname contain the regex match.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have and extra set of curly braces around first/last name fields. The way it is written now, your $or clause is:

(($regex AND $regex) OR null).

Try this:

```
{
  "$or": [
      {
        "firstname": {
          "$regex": ".*Za"
        }
      },
      {
        "lastname": {
          "$regex": ".*Za"
         }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how long it would have taken me to see that